# MS Access + IIS + Impersonation = 'Unspecified Error'?

Tags: .net, ms-access, iis-7

I have an ASP .NET (2.0) app that connects to an Access database over a network share using impersonation and basic authentication in IIS. Everything was working fine up until today, when I started getting weird 'Unspecified Error' error messages. I ended up doing an IIS reset to resolve the problem, but I'm trying to figure out why it may have happened in the first place.

Any ideas? Here is my connection string: 
provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = \REMOTESERVER\LocalDatabases$\database.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see that there is a real question here. There is certainly not enough information to help you.

Comment: That's not particularly his fault. "Unspecified Error" is notoriously difficult to diagnose so asking for complete "shot in the dark" suggestions seems legitimate to me.

Comment: I'd disagree somewhat.  Certainly there is more information in the exception than that (a stack trace, inner exception, but SOMETHING).

Answer (score 0):

If everything was working fine up until today, something must have changed. If no one has changed the code or configuration for IIS, then it must be something else on the server (or the network share).

Given that we just went though a patch-Tuesday, I would suspect that someone updated either the webserver or the network server. See if there is a patch you can roll-back .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OLEDB, but with ODBC, it is often the case that more than one error is returned by ODBC, and the last one is all you get notified about until you specifically check the ODBC errors collection. Perhaps OLEDB is returning more than one error, and one of the other errors in the error collection might be more illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are closing properly the database at the end of your routines. This can cause these messages eventually.

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

I saw "Unspecified Error" when I was configuring a new server. I was trying to impersonate a domain user to access a database located in a network drive.

To fix the issue, I added the domain user to local Administrators group. That solved the issue for me.